# Cannot assign XOR result to a BitArray type variable. How to fix this code?

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to XOR the two LSBs of a blue byte of a pixel and store the result in an index of a BitArray variable, but C# gives me casting error of

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

I know C# treats XOR operation as `int` but I can't get this code fixed. Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(fname);
    BitArray cipherBits = new BitArray(cipherStringSize * sizeof(Char) * 8);
    int cipherBitCounter = 0;
    Color pixel;
    byte[] cipherByte = new byte[cipherBits.Length/8];

            for (int i = 0; i < img.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < img.Width; j++)
                {
                    if (cipherBitCounter <= cipherBits.Length)
                    {
                        pixel = img.GetPixel(i, j);
                        cipherBits[cipherBitCounter] = ((pixel.B >> 1) & 1) ^ ((pixel.B) & 1); //error here
                        cipherBitCounter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       //do something else
                    }
                }
```

Comment: On which line exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably compare to 1:

```
cipherBits[cipherBitCounter] =( ((pixel.B >> 1) & 1) ^ ((pixel.B) & 1) ) == 1; //error here
```

But it is probably better to use Convert.ToBoolean:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
cipherBits[cipherBitCounter] = Convert.ToBoolean( ((pixel.B >> 1) & 1) ^ ((pixel.B) & 1) ); //error here
```

Comment: I get the error: "cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'"

Comment: You can probably compare to 1 to get a bool.  Might be nice to store right side in a temporary variable to make the code cleaner.

Comment: I tried both way, but all the bits in the cipherBits BitArray continuously remain 'false' no matter what.

Comment: add some logging... log out the value of ((pixel.B >> 1) & 1) ^ ((pixel.B) & 1)  - log out the value of pixel.B, figure out why the value is always false, you can also log out the intermediate values, like: (pixel.B >> 1)   ((pixel.B >> 1) & 1), etc.